# What is the easy way to set all empty string textbox ("") to null value in Csharp winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, null, string

Suppose I don't want to use

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text))
{
     textbox1.Text = null;
}
```

for every textbox controls in form, is there a easier way to do it ?

Comment: @Sun - you cannot set text value of textbox to null value...if you set it must be blank nothing else...

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? hardly makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the ControlCollection of the given form, e.g. frmMain.Controls
Now this will be the basic Control object, so you would need a test to see if it is of type TextBox.

.NET 2.0 - you'll have to check this manually
.NET 3.0+ - use the `.OfType<TextBox>` extension method to give you only a list of `IEnumerable<TextBox>`

Note that iterating through this from the form will only give you text boxes on that form. If you bind text boxes to a container it won't show up there.

Safest bet would be to write a recursive function that walks through all the control collections and passes the reference to your test function to perform your test and update.

Answer (score 3):

Simple way is Loop through every control, see the below code

```
 foreach (Control C in this.Controls)
 {
       if (C is TextBox)
       {
            if (C.Text == "")
            {
                 C.Text = null;
             }
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

It is one more way

```
foreach(Control txt in this.Controls)
{
   if(txt.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
         if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text))
            txt.Text = null;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Here you are basically setting the exact same value, this does not make it `null`.

Comment: I hope now it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
      if (c.GetType().FullName == "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox")
      {
          TextBox t = (TextBox)c;
          t.Clear();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a derived control from textbox control, and override its text property.